# Create an interactive 3d scatter plot with D3.js and Three.js with json data

Tags: json, d3.js, 3d, three.js, scatter-plot

I am learing and searching for an example of an interactive 3d scatter plot, which is using D3.js and Three.js.

How can I make a scatter plot with 3 axis (x, y, z)? And also how to combine it with Three.js to make it into 3D? On the other hand, I have made a json file and hoping to import into the scatter plot. Do I need a web server to import them?

Extra question: In the scatter plot, I would also like to do some interaction, such as zoom in and out, filtering data display, and also putting different data type into the x,y,z axis?

If there is any example from data visualization site or other resources you know, may I ask to share with me and I can look at?

Comment: Can you please provide some examples of what exactly do you want to achieve ? What kind of 3d scatter plot ? Aren't current libraries enough for what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 4):

I created a 3d plugin for d3js for exactly that purpose.
Please take a look at this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/1c15016ae5b5f11508f92852057136b5).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that [overt self-promotion is not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). If you want to draw more attention to your project, you _are_ allowed to link it in your profile page.

Comment: Can you please look at this question regarding d3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312494/convert-2d-shape-into-3d-in-d3-js-and-adjust-height-according-to-the-value-in-an

Comment: @Niekes can you tell me is that possible to have all three axes on your example with rotation ? Because I'm trying to do not find any catch. Thanks.